# Ошибка в преобразовании ISO-8859-1 в UTF8

Tags: python, кодировка, requests

html, который возвращает POST имеет кодировку ISO-8859-1, при попытке преобразования в UTF-8 выпадает в ошибку.

```py
import requests

url = "http://___"
payload='some text'
headers = {some headers}
r=requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
r.encoding
```

> ISO-8859-1

```
html=r.text.encode('ISO-8859-1').decode('UTF-8')
```

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 226: invalid continuation byte

Если поискать пример конкретного текста, то можно увидеть такое:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
div=soup.find('div', {'class': 'thumbnail_3'})
mystr=div.find_all('td')[0].get_text()
print(mystr)
```

> Âàðèàíòû íàèìåíîâàíèÿ ïðîäóêöèè

Comment: Просто r.content передавайте вместо r.text (байты вместо неправильно декодированного текста), тогда bs сам по мета-тегам определит правильную кодировку: soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

Comment: И еще, перед получением текста из ответа можно кодировку заменить: `r.encoding = 'cp1251'` `print(r.text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня перекодировалось при таком составе кодировок:

```
text = 'Âàðèàíòû íàèìåíîâàíèÿ ïðîäóêöèè'
print(text.encode('CP1252').decode('CP1251', errors='ignore'))
# Варианты наименования продукции
```

Могу посоветовать в спорных случаях в список свести себе все варианты поддерживаемых кодировок с https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings. И в цикле их все попробовать с распечаткой применить. Так найдете нужную комбинацию кодировок.